# Laravel - update one to one field

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have an update post form, where I need to update the name of the post in posts table and the associated text within the text table. I can't seem to get it to work at all.

Model - Post.php

```
   public function text()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Text');
    }
```

Model - Text.php

```
  public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }
```

Controller - PostController.php

```
public function updateQuestionForm($id)
    {

        $post = Post::find($id);

        $input = Input::all();

        $rules = array(
            'text'  => 'required',
        );

        $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

        if ($validation->fails()) {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
        } else {

            $post->title = Input::get('title');
            $post->save();

            $text = $post->text();
            $text->text = Input::get('text');
            $post->text()->save($text);

            $message = "Post updated";
            return Redirect::to('question/'.$post->id.'/'.$post->slug.'/')->with('message', $message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Change `$text = $post->text();` to `$text = $post->text;` and it should work. And make sure you tell us what `can't make it work at all` means, ie does it throw exception? does it save unexpected value? you know.

Comment: Simple as that. I couldn't see it.  It now works, thank you.